# Swift Firestore trouble deleting an element in an array nested in document

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Thanks for having a look not sure what I am missing?

Here is what my data looks like in Firestore

[image]

Here is Comment Model. Note I should have shown this in original question for more context.

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Comment: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var userId: String
    var storyId: String
    var commentText: String
    var createdAt: Date
}
```

Here is method where I am deleting Firestore data. No error is being thrown? The print statements in method print the expected firestore document id and the whole comment object in question But it also prints the success case and nothing changes in UI or FireStore.

```
func deleteComment(id: String, comment: Comment) {
        print(id, comment)
        //prints firestore document id and whole comment object
        
        let commentData: [String: Any] = [
            "id" : comment.id as Any,
            "userId" : comment.userId,
            "storyId" : comment.storyId,
            "commentText" : comment.commentText,
            "createdAt" : comment.createdAt
        ]
        
        store.collection(path).document(id).updateData([
            "comments" : FieldValue.arrayRemove([commentData])
        ]) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to delete comment: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }  else {
                print("Successfully deleted comment")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're using "comment" (no `s`) in your first example and "comments` (with an `s`) in your second one.

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks I fixed my typo. I still have something going on though

Comment: It looks like `arrayRemove` needs the whole object passed to it -- you're only passing the `id`.

Comment: This looks like it may be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733560/removing-an-array-item-from-firestore-not-working-when-array-contains-date/67742380#67742380

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks I just saw your comment, that is correct it was the date type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a type thing the createdAt property in my model is of type date. I edited my original question to show model for more context

So I for time being I just removed the createdAt property
Thanks to @jnpdx for all the help.

```
 func deleteComment(docId: String,comment: Comment) {
        print("ID here",docId)
        print("Comment",comment)

        let commentData: [String: Any] = [
            "id" : comment.id,
            "userId" : comment.userId,
            "storyId" : comment.storyId,
            "commentText" : comment.commentText
        ]
   
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.store.collection(self.path).document(docId).updateData([
                "comments" : FieldValue.arrayRemove([commentData])
            ]) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Unable to delete comment: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }  else {
                    print("Successfully deleted comment")
                }
            }
        }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only removing the `id` from the `comments` section. You should remove the whole data as you do when you add a comment.

```swift
func deleteComment(id: String, comment: Comment) {
        print(id, comment.id)
         // print results QDobPXyOM2WSLUA0j7Cj 
         //55BAE423-B32F-41E3-8B2CB594BF9002D7

        let commentData: [String: Any] = [
            "id" : comment.id as Any,
            "userId" : comment.userId,
            "storyId" : comment.storyId,
            "commentText" : comment.commentText,
            "createdAt" : comment.createdAt
        ]

        let docRef = store.collection(path).document(id)

        docRef.updateData([
            "comments" : FieldValue.arrayRemove([commentData])
        ])
    }
```

Comment: I tried adding whole object still nothing happens

Comment: I refactored my question added a completion also